# Rspec error, "undefined method 'downcase' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

I keep getting this error when running my Rspec test and can't figure out why. I'm pretty new to Rails (and programming in general) so any direction or help would be much appreciated!

***EDIT: Here is a link to the repo, if anyone would like to sift through it and/or replicate the error.***  https://github.com/FluxAnimus/sample_app/tree/sign-up

```
Failures:

1) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:5:in `gravatar_for'
 # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1766857043046396980_38603940'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/helpers/users_helper.rb:5:in `gravatar_for'
 # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__1766857043046396980_38603940'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.46129 seconds
39 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages profile page
```

I'm in Chapter 7.13 of the Ruby on Rails tutorial. The tests cleared just fine until I added the Gravatar code and FactoryGirls Gem.

/app/helpers/users_helper.rb file

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end
.
.
.
end
```

And the last reference: app/views/users/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<h1>
  <%= gravatar_for @user %>
  <%= @user.name %> 
</h1>
```

Here is the factory file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name     "Michael Hartl"
    email    "michael@example.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using the definition of `gravatar_for` in the tutorial, `downcase` is only referenced in the context of `user.email.downcase` which means that `user` *is* defined, but the `email` method/attribute of `user` returns `nil`. You can also go by the filename, method and line number provided in the stack trace to identifying the offending code.

Update: In your `User` model you, had a `before_save` call which included the following:

```
self.email = email.downcase!
```

Since `downcase!` returns `nil`, this has the effect of setting `email` to `nil`. Per the tutorial, you can use either of the following instead:

```
self.email.downcase!
```

or:

```
self.email = email.downcase
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the definition in the tutorial. I've added the pages in the stack trace. Still can't seem to find the issue. Again, my apologies, I'm pretty much completely new at all this. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious at this point. It may be worth noting that everything appears to be working correctly when I launch the app.

Comment: To just throw some things out there: a) If you're using guard/spork, have you restarted it?, b) Is your test database up to date (e.g. with `rake test:prepare`), c) Is your `UsersController#show` method properly defined?

Comment: I'm not actually using guard/spork, though I have the Gems included in the Gemfile. My tests run very quickly, so I decided to not use them after all. I've updated the question with my Users Controller show file. Looks right to me, but I could certainly be wrong.

Comment: Well, I found a solution, but I'm not sure it's eloquent. For whatever reason my user.email variable wasn't a string, so I changed the code in the UsersHelper file to read     gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.to_s.downcase)

Comment: Actually, that just turns the `nil` object into the string `"nil"`, so it doesn't get at whatever issue you have. Further, I installed your repository from github and it runs fine.  Your sure your test database is set up?  In any event, if I were you, I would put print statements in around the `User` object creation in your model.

Comment: Thanks Peter. It's certainly odd, because if I raise user.email.inspect in the def gravator_for method it shows the email address "example@railstutorial.org". That's what gave me the idea of just adding .to_s before downcase. I'm not sure how to make sure my test database is set up though. It's looking like print statements are going to be my best bet. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I just realized that the repository I downloaded didn't include your failing test or have FactoryGirl reflected in the Gemfile.  Did your link perhaps point to an older version?  I'm still not too familiar with dealing with versions on github.

Comment: If you can print out `user.email` in `gravatar_for` then I'm really confused.  That makes no sense at all with the error you're getting.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what happened before, but I just got the latest commit and I've reproduced the problem. Yeah! Now for the fun part. Back in a bit ...

Comment: Good catch Peter. To clarify, `downcase!` modifies the original string in place and returns nil. `downcase` leaves the original string alone and returns a new one.

Comment: Awesome! Excellent catch Peter. I really appreciate you taking the time to comb through it. I just implemented your suggestions and all is well.

Comment: And thank you for the clarification Andrew, you two certainly helped me understand both the solution and the underlying reason/cause.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable that you think is a string, but it's actually `nil`.

You can't call `downcase` on `nil`, so you're getting this error.

Welcome to Ruby, you'll be seeing that one a lot.  :)

**EDIT**

I see you've added some code to the question.

As the error message says, it's user_helper.rb line 5:

```
gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
```

It's `user.email` that is `nil`.  I'm guessing that your FactoryGirl factory isn't assigning an email address to the user.

Comment: Haha, thanks. I figured that's what it was, so I appreciate the confirmation. Any idea on how to track that down? I've checked my user variable and it appears to be a string everywhere it's referenced.

Comment: Your `user` variable *should* be an instance of the `User` class, not a string. It most likely is, since we know that `user.email` evaluates successfully.

Comment: Edited my answer to say `user.email` is the culprit.

Comment: Great! That's what I was thinking as well. Just not sure how to correct it now. Any tips?

Comment: I made sure to check factory as well. I included the code in my original question. I don't see anything wrong with it though.

Comment: It does look correct, so I'm not sure.  Guess you'll have to try putting some print statements in your page.  (I'm not familiar with unit testing views like this, so it's possible I'm missing something.)

Comment: I appreciate the effort Grant!