# Railstutorial ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the Hartl tutorial for the second time only this time I'm trying to modify it for a personal project. Now I'm stumped as to why I can't get my test to pass (or the edit settings page to render). The issues is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006056/rspec-error-undefined-method-downcase-for-nilnilclass) except the error is returning for email and not downcase and I'm using the default test suite and not Rspec.

Here is the error code:

```
ERROR["test_unsuccessful_edit", UsersEditTest, 0.7226080000109505]
 test_unsuccessful_edit#UsersEditTest (0.72s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
            app/helpers/users_helper.rb:6:in `gravatar_for'
            app/views/users/edit.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_users_edit_html_erb___3727331653542369693_70276142435800'
            test/integration/users_edit_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersEditTest>'
```

And each file referenced:

app/helpers/user_helper

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    size = options[:size]
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

app/views/users/edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<% provide(:button_text, 'Edit account') %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">change</a>
    </div>

    <%= render 'form' %>

  </div>
</div>
```

test/integration/users_edit_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersEditTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "unsuccessful edit" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get edit_user_path(@user)
    assert_template 'users/edit'
    patch user_path(@user), params: { user: { name:  "",
                                              email: "foo@invalid",
                                              password:              "foo",
                                              password_confirmation: "bar" } }

    assert_template 'users/edit'
  end
end
```

And, because it was the issue in the other question, here is the relevant part of the user model. If I add '!' to the email.downcase method at the end, all the other tests that use email fail, but without it they all pass (except this one).

app/model/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save :downcase_email
```

...

```
private

    # Converts email to all lower-case
    def downcase_email
      self.email = email.downcase
    end
```

Here is the user controller

```
app/controllers/user_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = 'Welcome to the Sample App'
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I don't know if this helps at all, but when I run Rubocop I also get this warning specific to the user helper that is in the error:

app/helpers/users_helper.rb:5:5: W: Lint/UselessAssignment: Useless assignment to variable - gravatar_id.
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set `@user` instance variable in your `UsersController#edit` action. Like so

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController 
...
  def edit
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id]) 
  end 
...
end
```

If this does not solve your problem, you can paste your `UsersController` code here that should help us solve your problems. However to make your code neater, you can set @user using a callback and call that callbacks on certain actions.

Comment: I just edited to add the user controller. I think I had it as an instance variable already, but maybe it's not written correctly

Comment: You don't have an `edit` action in your `UsersController` ?

Comment: Add the `edit` just like in my example and everything should be fine.

Comment: Oh no :( yep, I feel dumb now. I was staring so hard at the create and update highlights that I completely looked over missing that. Thank you!